# Nonpolar vs Polar Covelant Bonding

Tags: organic-chemistry, water

So I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the two. Looking specifically at water and carbon dioxide, CO2 is non-polar, because it is symmetrical and carbon shares two electrons with each oxygen and vice versa. But doesn't oxygen also share 1 electron with each hydrogen and vice versa? I know water isn't symmetrical, but for a molecule which I haven't seen the shape before how would I figure it out?

Comment: You've muddled it completely for yourself so no wonder you're confused.

Comment: What do you mean by I muddles it? Am I overthinking it?

Comment: It would help to read about VSEPR, the theory that predicts the shape of molecules.  https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/General_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Chemistry%3A_The_Central_Science_(Brown_et_al.)/09._Molecular_Geometry_and_Bonding_Theories/9.2%3A_The_VSEPR_Model

Answer (score 1):

Look at each bond separately. In $CO_2$, in each $C=O$ bond, electrons are shifted towards oxygen atom as is has more pulling tendency(electron affinity). Now there is a formation of $\delta+$ charge on carbon and $\delta-$ on oxygen. This forms a dipole and you write it vectorially. In carbon dioxide, the vectors are equal and at $180$ degrees, so they cancel out and net dipole moment is 0, thus nonpolar molecule. Similarly, for the 2 $O-H$ bonds you get a net nonzero dipole moment, leading to a polar molecule.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for help. I think I misinterpreted something that was written in the textbook